# Multi parameter query for tags search

Tags: ms-access

My database is composed by 2 tables:

- 'tests
- 'tags'

'tags' table is related to 'tests' table with a 'many to one' relation. The purpose of the 'tags' table is to assign tags to each test so the user is able to query the records in the table 'tests' which have specific tags.
For this purporse I made a parameter query but I'm able to input only one parameter per time where instead I need to input multiple parameter (tags) because each record in the 'tests' table can have multiple tags. I saw it's possible to use operators such as 'AND' and 'OR' in the criteria field of the query coloumns but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I think [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-parameters-to-ask-for-input-when-running-a-query-c2806d3d-d500-45a8-8507-ec6af351b6ed) should help. Otherwise, try googling something like "access multiple parameters".

Comment: Say a user searches using two tags, `ms-access` and `sql`: would you expected it to match a test that was tagged with only the `ms-access` tag and not the `sql` tag?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to collect tags for searching. You can do this using list box with multi selection or custom form with checkboxes similar to quick filters in Excel. Collecting tags as free text is possible, but users don't like this method.

Then save collected tags to special new table and join it with your existing tables. Query results will be limited by selected tags only.

As alternative you can create dynamic record source for the form with results and use `In`. Generate SQL string like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM MyQueryWithFullResults WHERE tag IN ('tag1','tag2','tag3')"
```

And use it as record source for form or as SQL for recordset

Comment: I'm sorry Sir. I admit I didn't understand very well Your solution. Instead to have a form to input the parameter of my query I have to create a table related to both my tables to be populated with the parameters I want to be searched and then run a query on those parameters? I'm not sure how to make access do that because the only method I know is to make it search a single paramter or the value within a textbox in a form - but I don't know how to make it query only the record within this table that are related to the records in the 'tests' table that have the specified tags. Thanks

Comment: I tried writing this string into the criteria argument: [input tag1] And [input tag 2] but it only search for records that have both tags within it

Comment: Perhaps as Ivan suggested I might create multiple queries and unify their results.

Comment: I think the OP is saying it should match *all* tags input. Your query using `IN` will match *any one* tag. I think in relational terms they want `MyQueryWithFullResults DIVIDED BY SpecialNewTable`.